# The process qmake.exe exited with code 2 - first time with Qt and Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, spaces

Downloaded Qt and Qt Creator. In Qt Creator I can run example programs. Created new project - Qt empty project. Added new cpp-file with code example from [Qt site](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqt.html) - first one. When I press "Run", "Build" or "Rebuild" I've got this output

```
01:41:24: Running steps for project First...
01:41:24: Starting: "C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin\qmake.exe" "C:\Documents and Settings\Олексій\Qt Projects\First\First.pro" -r -spec win32-msvc2008 "CONFIG+=declarative_debug"
Cannot find file: c:\Documents and Settings\Олексій\Qt Projects\First\First.pro.
01:41:24: The process "C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin\qmake.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project First (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'qmake'
```

But there IS such file, it contains

```
SOURCES +=  Main.cpp
```

What is wrong? I didn't google the solution yet

Comment: With previous versions of Qt I had problems with spaces in project paths (Note that it installs itself to "C:\Qt: and not to "Program Files"). Try to move your project from "Documents and Settings" to some other location and rename "Qt Projects" to for example "Qt_Projects". As far as I remember it was mentioned in the docs to avoid spaces in project paths. I would also be carefull with cyrillic characters.

Comment: @doc thanks, it's it! Will you rewrite your comment as an answer so I will be able to accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NP Hate ;)

With previous versions of Qt I had problems with spaces in project paths (Note that it installs itself to "C:\Qt: and not to "Program Files"). Try to move your project from "Documents and Settings" to some other location and rename "Qt Projects" to for example "Qt_Projects". As far as I remember it was mentioned in the docs to avoid spaces in project paths.

I would also be carefull with Cyrillic characters

Comment: I checked with just Cyrillic name of folder without spaces - it was same error. Then I check with all Latin names with spaces - there where no error. So it seems that Qt Creator doesn't support Unicode properly..

Comment: @Hate Yes, it is very sensitive. I think that it is caused by cross-platform capabilities. There is no problem within the API and the framework itself on the other hand. It has very good support for I18N and L10N.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you must add to .pro file something like LIBS+=..