# QAbstractSocket no such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, spaces

I'm new to QT programming and this has got me perplexed. I've searched for an answer to this question but the answers I've found have not fixed my problem. Generally, the answers I've found online are saying to add `QT += network` to my .pro file. However I already have this in my .pro file and it has not been fixed.

Any suggestions?

.pro file

```
QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = firstproject
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
IB_API_with_Qt/src/IBClient.cpp \
IB_API_with_Qt/src/EQtClientSocket.cpp \
IB_API_with_Qt/src/EClientSocketBase.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/TwsSocketClientErrors.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/ScannerSubscription.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/OrderState.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/Order.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/IBClient.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/Execution.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/EWrapper.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/EQtClientSocket.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/EClientSocketBaseImpl.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/EClientSocketBase.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/EClient.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/Contract.h \
IB_API_with_Qt/include/CommonDefs.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

the error occurs in a header file where it says simply:

```
#include <QAbstractSocket>
```

And this is what the compile output provides me:

```
21:36:05: Running steps for project firstproject...
21:36:05: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
21:36:05: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -
    DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..
    \..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..
    \..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug"
    -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Terence\AppData
    \Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.5272.47.jom
    mainwindow.cpp
    c:\users\terence\documents\qt projects\firstproject\IB_API_with_Qt/include/IBClient.h(6) : fatal error C1083: Cannot 
    open include file: 'QAbstractSocket': No such file or directory
    jom: C:\Users\Terence\Documents\QT Projects\firstproject-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Debug
    \Makefile.Debug [debug\mainwindow.obj] Error 2
    jom: C:\Users\Terence\Documents\QT Projects\firstproject-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Debug\Makefile 
    [debug] Error 2
21:36:08: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
    Error while building/deploying project firstproject (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.0 MSVC2010 32bit (SDK))
    When executing step 'Make'
```

Comment: are you using qt version greater than 4? if so, you may need to add `network` in this line -> `greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets`.

Comment: @d_vj I am using QT greater than 4 but I just tried that suggestion and still same problem

Comment: The problem may be that directory `QT Projects` contains spaces. Try to rename it to for example `QtProjects`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095889/the-process-qmake-exe-exited-with-code-2-first-time-with-qt-and-qt-creator

Comment: @Chowza pls try doc's suggestion. that is very possible.

Comment: @Chowza I assume you've done the obvious and re-run qmake?  Your build does not even attempt to bring in the network library when `cl` is run.

Comment: @doc thank you. That works. I'm surprised I didn't find anything about the spacing. If you would like to add that I'll accept it as an answer tomorrow. Need some sleep now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt build may fail if project path contains spaces or non-ASCII characters.

[Documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/platform-notes-windows.html) mentions that you should not install Qt into directory containing spaces, but it should be better documented and explicitly warn that your project path may affect build process as well.

In your case include paths were set as relative to project path (e.g., `-I"..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui`), which contained space and because of that `cl` was unable to find header.

> **Related question:**
>   [The process qmake.exe exited with code 2 - first time with Qt and Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095889/the-process-qmake-exe-exited-with-code-2-first-time-with-qt-and-qt-creator)